# Ionic 2 using custom css

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an Ionic2 app (actually I am learning), and am trying to apply custom css to my component, however it is not successful.

**My app folder structure is as following:**
[image]

**My app.core.css:**

```
@import "../pages/start/start";

@import "../pages/farmList/farmList";

@import "../pages/slider/slider";

@import "../pages/farm/farm";
```

**My slider.component.ts**

```
<ion-slides #mySlider [options]="mySlideOptions" id="mySlides">

  <ion-slide >
    <div padding>
      <h1>Welcome to Swarms app</h1>
      <p>Here you can view, manage and manipulate all your data</p>
    </div>

  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <button (click)="goToHome()">Start</button>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

- I am trying to add some properties in *slider.scss* but it has no effect. How can apply some styles to it?
- Also, I created a folder 'img' like www/build/img and put few images in there, but on whenever I restart my ionic app with ionic serve, the folder is vanished, WHY?

**UPDATE:** First problem is solved, it was a simple typo in components where it had to be `styleUrls:['/slider.scss']`and not `styleUrls:['/slider.css']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I created a folder 'img' like www/build/img and put few images
>   in there, but on whenever I restart my ionic app with ionic serve, the
>   folder is vanished, WHY?

When you run `ionic serve` all the javascript and styles files are compiled and put together (among other tasks) in your `build` folder, and that's why if you put somethig there, is deleted.

In order to avoid that, you should put your images in `www\images` and then reference them in your code by doing:

`<img src="images/myImage.png" />`

======================

EDIT:

You can find more information about what's going on when you run `ionic serve` (and also `emulate`, `deploy` and `build`) by taking a look at your `gulpfile.js`:

```
/**
 * Ionic hooks
 * Add ':before' or ':after' to any Ionic project command name to run the specified
 * tasks before or after the command.
 */
gulp.task('serve:before', ['watch']);
gulp.task('emulate:before', ['build']);
gulp.task('deploy:before', ['build']);
gulp.task('build:before', ['build']);
```

And in the lasts lines of code of the `gulpfile.js` you can see this:

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del('www/build');
});
```

Which is what causes the `build` folder to be deleted.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for giving this extra info about gulf file, I didn't know gulp in much detail! That's the disadvantage of using boilerplate!

Answer (score 3):

Add a folder css in the src/assets folder. Put your css file there. In the src/index.html file, add this line 
`<link href="assets/css/yourCssFileName.css" rel="stylesheet">`
Then you can refer to anything in the css file in your other pages as what you normally do with web pages.

Comment: Nice answer. Solved my issue. Thank you mate ;-)